# Parse.com hangle one-to-many relation

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, one-to-many

I need save one-to-many relations in Parse, every Cathegory has to have several Questions ( max 4 ) and every Question has to have String for question and answer ( max 5 Strings ) and additionally 4 image ( not implemented yet ) and I need it to have online to updating "on air". And I am currently testing database service ( and now I decided for Parse but I need to save the relation between Cathegory and Question)

This is my code for Activity (fragment) :

```
            Question q1 = new Question("How much money cost new Skoda Fabia?", "300 " +
                    "000kc", "200 000kc", "100 000kc", "50 000kc");
            q1.saveInBackground();
            Question q2 = new Question("How much money cost new Skoda Felicia?", "300 " +
                    "000kc", "200 000kc", "100 000kc", "150 000kc");
            q2.saveInBackground();
            Question q3 = new Question("How much money cost new Skoda Octavia?", "500 " +
                    "000kc", "150 000kc", "100 000kc", "50 000kc");
            q3.saveInBackground();

            ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            questionArrayList.add(q1);
            questionArrayList.add(q2);
            questionArrayList.add(q3);

            ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("Cathegory");
            parseObject.put("Auto", questionArrayList);
            parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Save was sucesfully");
                    Log.d(TAG,"error was ? : " + (e == null ? "none" : e.getMessage()));
                }
            });
```

Category was created correctly but if I look at questions so there is only :
[Parse Problem Image](http://s29.postimg.org/c39zp0g5z/parse_Problem.jpg)

Question class code:

```
  @ParseClassName("Question")
public class Question extends ParseObject {
public static final String TAG = Question.class.getName();

private String question;
private String rightAnswer;
private String wrongAnswer1;
private String wrongAnswer2;
private String wrongAnswer3;

public Question(){
    //need for Parse
}

public Question(String question, String rightAnswer, String wrongAnswer1, String wrongAnswer2, String wrongAnswer3) {
    super();
    this.question = question;
    this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    this.wrongAnswer1 = wrongAnswer1;
    this.wrongAnswer2 = wrongAnswer2;
    this.wrongAnswer3 = wrongAnswer3;
}

public Question(String theClassName, String question, String rightAnswer, String wrongAnswer1, String wrongAnswer2, String wrongAnswer3) {
    super(theClassName);
    this.question = question;
    this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    this.wrongAnswer1 = wrongAnswer1;
    this.wrongAnswer2 = wrongAnswer2;
    this.wrongAnswer3 = wrongAnswer3;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake. Please be aware of this.

Right code of Question class :

```
 @ParseClassName("Question")
public class Question extends ParseObject {
public static final String TAG = Question.class.getName();

private String question;
private String rightAnswer;
private String wrongAnswer1;
private String wrongAnswer2;
private String wrongAnswer3;

public Question(){
    //need for Parse
}

public Question(String question, String rightAnswer, String wrongAnswer1, String wrongAnswer2, String wrongAnswer3) {
    super();
    super.put("question", question);
    super.put("rightAnswer", rightAnswer);
    super.put("wrongAnswer1", wrongAnswer1);
    super.put("wrongAnswer2", wrongAnswer2);
    super.put("wrongAnswer3", wrongAnswer3);
    this.question = question;
    this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    this.wrongAnswer1 = wrongAnswer1;
    this.wrongAnswer2 = wrongAnswer2;
    this.wrongAnswer3 = wrongAnswer3;
}

public Question(String theClassName, String question, String rightAnswer, String wrongAnswer1, String wrongAnswer2, String wrongAnswer3) {
    super(theClassName);
    super.put("question", question);
    super.put("rightAnswer", rightAnswer);
    super.put("wrongAnswer1", wrongAnswer1);
    super.put("wrongAnswer2", wrongAnswer2);
    super.put("wrongAnswer3", wrongAnswer3);
    this.question = question;
    this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    this.wrongAnswer1 = wrongAnswer1;
    this.wrongAnswer2 = wrongAnswer2;
    this.wrongAnswer3 = wrongAnswer3;
}
```

}